# "Lost connection to MySQL server during query python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am using `@transaction.atomic decorator` 
I am using python and django 
and I got this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /create_project
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 422, in commit
    self._read_ok_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 396, in _read_ok_packet
    pkt = self._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 656, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 702, in _read_bytes
    CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 212, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 261, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 422, in commit
    self._read_ok_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 396, in _read_ok_packet
    pkt = self._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 656, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 702, in _read_bytes
    CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

What do I do??
UPD: I am using cloud 9 ide (c9.io) so can this be connected to performance issue since the c9 servers are not so robust?

Comment: It may happen if your query is too slow and get dropped by timout.

Comment: And the timeout configuration can be changed in mysql server configuration file. Check it